# redirecting after reload on JQM app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is the schema:
I have a page with a list (*#list*). When you click on an item, a details page (*#details*) is shown, almost entirely dynamicly built with data from an indexedDB. Everything works fine, except that: when you are on *#details* and click the refresh button (or f5 or whatever makes the page reload) I want to redirect to *#list* page, but I can't do it.
This is what I'm trying now:

```
 $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#details',  function(e){
      if (location.hash == '#details'){
          console.log("reloading details page");
      }
 });
```

I think I?m right with the event trigger, because I get the console log when and only when I reload the #details page, but none of these lines did the job:

```
 $("#list").trigger("create");
 $.mobile.loadPage("#list");
 $.mobile.navigate( "#list" );
 $.mobile.changePage("#list");
```

Please, help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about this question. As it was supossed, `$.mobile.changePage("#list")` works fine on this. The problem was a slider-plugin I was calling on the same page, that was created before adding dynamic content and was fired before `changePage()`. I solved it by simply calling the plugin when creating the content, not before.